# How can I tell if Shillelagh has been cast on a quarterstaff?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Are there any visible indications that would indicate that Shillelagh has been cast upon a quarterstaff? Assume that the spell was cast out of sight.

The rules don't say either way. I'm just wondering if I cast it before entering combat if the spell effect would be detectable (other than via detect magic).

> **School** transmutation; **Level** druid 1
>   **Target:** one touched nonmagical oak club or quarterstaff
>
> Your own nonmagical club or quarterstaff becomes a weapon with a +1 enhancement bonus
>       on attack and damage rolls. A quarterstaff gains this enhancement for both ends of the 
>       weapon. It deals damage as if it were two size categories larger (a Small club or 
>       quarterstaff so transmuted deals 1d8 points of damage, a Medium 2d6, and a Large 3d6), +1 
>       for its enhancement bonus. These effects only occur when the weapon is wielded by you. If 
>       you do not wield it, the weapon behaves as if unaffected by this spell.

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27203/which-school-of-magic-do-magical-weapons-and-armor-auras-radiate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Knowledge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/knowledge) (arcana) to identify a spell by its effect, without having seen it cast. The DC is 20 + spell level (i.e. DC 21 for *shillelagh* as cast by a druid).

Historical note: this was a Spellcraft check in 3.5. Seeing as it works on divine spells like *shillelagh*, I’d argue it should still be one. I have no idea why Paizo felt the need to change it.

Comment: When you say "effect" are you indicating that the opponent won't be able tell until struck by the shillelagh enhanced staff? Makes sense. They'd immediately notice that the staff if packing a lot more punch than as staff of the same size normally would.

Comment: @KornMuffin No, *shillelagh* is a transmutation spell, so the effect would be whatever changes it applies to the staff. I would assume those changes would be visible, and you could use the check to see them for what they are.

Comment: Thanks. Agreed. Like you said since it's a transmutation school spell there is some physical alteration even if the spell description doesn't state so and even though the effects only apply when used by the caster.